# How to print text that after iteration in fastreport?

Tags: iteration, fastreport

my <Material Code ..... </Material is an iteration which lists all materials , i need to print text for example  after this iteration ends.

[fastreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izexf.png)

I have tried different codes, but struggled to get them to work.